# mongodb Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb in Ubuntu14.04 server

I was not able to connect to mongodb via "mongoimport", "mongodump", "mongostat", etc. It always show "no reachable server"

```
mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file dataset.json
2015-08-25T13:08:29.802+0800    [........................] test.restaurants 0.0 B/11.3 MB (0.0%)
2015-08-25T13:08:30.306+0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2015-08-25T13:08:30.306+0800    imported 0 documents
```

Somehow, I was able to connect with mongo shell

```
mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

At first, I doubt if it cause by my iptables, so I flush all iptables rules and create rules for ALL accept, but it still same

```
 sudo iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

I search the stackOverflow and google and someone told marked off 
bind_ip or set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0, I tried all but still failed.

Below are my mangodb config, would any one can help me to check?
Thanks for your help

```
james@localhost:~$ cat /etc/mongod.conf 
# mongod.conf

# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

port = 27017

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces. 
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal = true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname
# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

Comment: Your `mongod` process is clearly not running. Look at the log `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` for reasons why. Also make sure you followed all the instructions on [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). Try to start the service, or restart the machine. Clean install if necessary.

Comment: Submitting this as an answer as I don't have the privilege to comment. I have a 3 member Replica Set (version 3.4) and faced the same issue with the below command. mongoimport --db test --drop rides.json Got the same error with the below command suggested by [whythecode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5000167/whythecode),<br/> mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --db test rides.json The following command was able to import mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1:27018 --db test rides.json Note that the primary was running on 27018. Also, it wasn't necessary to reset the Replica Set or run it as standalone.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A temporary workaround is to add the `host` param to your `mongoimport` call, letting mongo know that the host is your own machine (`127.0.0.1`):

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1
```

The full command in your case is then:

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 \
  --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file dataset.json
```

(Source: [ranjeetcao @ mongorestore Failed: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350861/5000167))

---

**Update:**

Updating to Mongo >= 3.0.7 should solve the issue

(Source: [Colin Marshall @ mongorestore Failed: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139963/5000167))

---

**Update 2:**

It seems the Bug [is still happening for some users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195997/mongodb-failed-error-connecting-to-db-server-no-reachable-servers/32452543?noredirect=1#comment60720573_32452543).

There's also an open JIRA issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-620).

(Source: [James Chien @ this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197841/5000167))

---

**Update 3:**

In some cases, this can be caused by Mongo running as a ReplicaSet. To solve this, as far as I've seen, one can either disable the ReplicaSet functionality or reset it. See:

- [How to reset MongoDB replica set settings](https://serverfault.com/a/424714)
- [How to convert a MongoDB replica set to a stand alone server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16914281/5000167)

(Source: [Maxim Yefremov @ mongorestore Failed: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34316860/5000167))

Comment: The workaround works great. If you want to go a step further and fix the problem so you don't have to use the workaround then see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33139963/2755888

Comment: hey, thanks for the heads-up! I'll update the answer to reflect it

Comment: Thanks, it works! For whatever reason, this is still happening in version 3.2.4...

Comment: @Leonli OMG, seriously? glad to help then!

Comment: It still happens in `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3` even using `--host 127.0.0.1` and having the `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` in the `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` file.

Comment: Adding host doesn't work, however, `service mongod restart` does fix it temporarily.

Comment: hi @Ajoy, could it be that in your case it's related to the replSet issue? Please see Update 3. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide host option try the following command :

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 -d dbName -c collectionName --file output.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11097993)

Comment: why not? The main answer only "mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1", so new guys will be confused about it and they can use full command.

Comment: @shemeermali you're right that it's better to stipulate the full command - the answer has been updated. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To provide the options **host** and **port**

```
mongoimport --host X.X.X.X --port 27017 --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer by this links https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-620
It seem it is a mongodb tools bugs that doesn't resolved yet.
Not sure if anyone know if the latest tools have fixed the issue?

BTW, I uninstall the mongodb-tools 3.x and reinstall to 2.6.0 that resolved the problem

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org-tools
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools=2.6.0

mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file dataset.json
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2015-08-25T15:19:59.494+0800 dropping: test.restaurants
2015-08-25T15:20:00.089+0800 check 9 25359
2015-08-25T15:20:00.089+0800 imported 25359 objects
```

Answer (score 2):

If TLS is enabled with authentication then use the below format from the dump location

```
mongorestore --host=example.com --port=27017 --username=user_name  --authenticationDatabase=admin --ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

Comment: Thanks just needed the `--ssl` flag and then it worked.

Comment: for me I needed authenticationDatabase

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer for those who are struggling with the same issue while using MongoDB Atlas.

I tried to follow the offical guides like [Seed with mongorestore](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongorestore/) and [Load File with mongoimport](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/) but received the same `no reachable servers` error.

I tried to change the command arguments over and over - nothing changed.

But then  **I navigated inside my cluster to the "Command Line Tools" tab and saw the exact command I should run** for `mongorestore`, `mongodump`, `mongoimport`,`mongoexport` etc':

[image]

Adding as inline the full command:

```
mongorestore --host 
<cluster-name>-shard-0/
<cluster-name>-shard-00-00-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017,
<cluster-name>-shard-00-01-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017,
<cluster-name>-shard-00-02-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017 
--ssl 
--username <User-Name> 
--password <PASSWORD> 
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

The `mongorestore` comand can be replaced with `mongodump`,`mongoimport`,`mongoexport` etc'.

(*) Prefer copying the command directly from dashboard because the DNS of the replica-sets might change.

(**) MongoDB shell version v4.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

For someone using Mongo Atlas and `json` file for import into collection:

```sh
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@your-cluster.xxxx.mongodb.net/<db> -c <collection> --file import.json --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 1):

For mongodb docker compose user the below command to seed the database

```
CMD mongoimport --uri mongodb://mongodb:27017/testdb --collection users --type json --file /init.json --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still facing this issue with MongoDB Atlas, just update your mongoDB version to more than 4.0.0. and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and downloaded MongoDB Compass and used the connection string from Atlas for [image: For NodeJS version 2.2.12 or later]

and that connection worked like a charm.

After that I went ahead and added the data using the `Add Data` option and uploaded the file which i want to `mongoimport`

Answer (score 0):

I used mongo atlas to import CSV file to the cluster, I faced the same issue I tried many different solutions mentioned here but no one worked, I get back to the documentation this one worked for me, go to the dashbord and click on the name of your cluster, in the extreme right there is tab called **command-line tools**
Data Import and Export Tools you will find how to import to your cluster

`mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://admin:<PASSWORD>@<NAME>.mongodb.net/<DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>`

if you are uploading csv file add --headerline after type

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you download latest version Mongo Database tool and it will work from the example website shows.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation/

[mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport) | imports content from an Extended JSON, CSV, or TSV export

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://usernmae:<PASSWORD>@monghosturl-part.mongodb.net/<DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>
```

[mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport) | produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance

```
mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://usernmae:<PASSWORD>@monghosturl-part.mongodb.net/<DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --out <FILENAME>
```

[image: CMD output]

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed mongodb through homebrew then you can simply start mongodb through

```
brew services start mongodb
```

Then access the shell by

```
mongo
```

You can shut down your db by

```
brew services stop mongodb
```

For more options

```
brew info mongodb
```

Answer (score -2):

```
mongorestore --db <thedb> --host=127.0.0.1 --port=<port> --drop path/db
```

Comment: You should explain your answer in detail so future people can understand what you're doing here (Just edit the question)

Comment: This will fails as well with `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3`

Comment: Great @Machavity.